# Export large Powerpivot table without data connection

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerquery

I'm on Excel 2013

Is it possible to EXPORT a powerpivot table and have FULL pivot table drop down functionality without the connected data?

1) I'm using slicers as filters and want to export specific files based on the Filtered Names

2) Would non Power Pivot / Power Query users be able to view my workbook? (I'm thinking probably not)

I've scoured forums and stackoverflow and was unable to find a clear answer.

I've tested it myself and disabled connection and it looks like the LAST format the PowerPivot table was showing would be the view/data that the user sees.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your test results. Anyone on Excel 2016 / Office 365 should get full functionality.

You might want to try the free Power BI service, where you can upload your Power Pivot model to the cloud and then connect to it using the Power BI Publisher Add-In.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-publisher-for-excel/#connect-to-data-in-power-bi

Comment: This might not work for my purposes, as I'm trying to send the power pivot tables externally as files.  Thanks!  

Is there a way to export the powerpivot table data into a regular excel spreadsheet and create a pivot table from there?  I know pivot tables can still function without the source data tab.

Comment: Actually it might still work well for your scenario - in Power BI you can share dashboards and their associated datasets with external users.  So just create a trivial dashboard (e.g. 1 card with the refresh date) and share that with them to establish access.

Comment: Otherwise I imagine you could create a Flattened PivotTable (in the PP Manage window, under Home / PivotTable) and add every column.  If your model is big than at some point Excel will explode, but you might get lucky.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a CSV file with your data as your data source in powerpivot and just point your data model at the CSV.  I do this to slim down big models.  The data lives in the powerpivot cache level but is not a literal tab in your workbook also much smaller footprint.  Works like a tiny database connection. Go to the powerpivot screen choose "From other sources" on the home ribbon, and scroll to the bottom for a text file or CSV.  Easiest way to make a pseudo-data mart.

I guess I am not sure what you mean by export the table, The pivot would show without the data connection, but without the full model behind it in the data layer changing anything would just lock it up.